# Не компилируется Java программа в IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java

[image: error:Cannot run program]

При компиляции программы вылезает ошибка:

> Error:Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java"
>   (in directory "C:\Users\andre.IdeaIC2016\system\compile-server"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо для начала установить JDK на комп. А также добавить её в IDE. И проект.

- В меню выбираем: `File` → `Project Structure`
- Слева внизу выбираем `Platform Settings` → `SDKs`. Здесь добавить свою новую JDK.
- А в `Platform Settings` → `Project` надо выбрать JDK, c которой хочешь работать. В данном случае это та, которую только что добавил.

Что-то типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]