# При каждом изменении кода и последующей компиляции выдает ошибку - Error:java: Cannot find JDK '1.8' for module 'MyProjects'

Tags: intellij-idea, java

При первом запуске только что написанного кода проблем нет. Но когда я делаю в нем какие-то исправления и потом запускаю, то выдает ошибку:

> Information:05/01/17 16:56 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 957ms
>
> Information:Module "MyProjects" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
>
> Error:java: Cannot find JDK '1.8' for module 'MyProjects'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать, чтобы такого не было?

Мой код:

```
package com.softserve.edu.task1;

/**
 * Created by Администратор on 05/01/17.
 */
public class Chess {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int h = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int l =Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++){
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
            }

                else {
                for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" *");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у вас есть jdk 1.8?  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607688/191482  - может поможет

Comment: да, есть. И путь к нему верный. Дело в том еще, что когда выбрасывает эту ошибку, то я через Project Strusture удаляю sdk и заново добавляю. После этого компиллируется. Но, если я опять исправляю код, то снова та же ошибка

Comment: А можете показать ваш код? на всякий случай. Добавьте его в вопрос.  И это полная цитата возникающей ошибки? ..........и еще: какая версия IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: добавила код и скрин ошибки

Comment: Охохох.)) можно добить тогда скринами со вкладок  `Project Structure → Project Settings → Project` и `Project Structure → Platform Settings → SDKs` )) ......еще раньше была такая проблема в какой-то версии Intellij. Помогало обновление версии...сомневаюсь что щас та же проблема может быть конечно.

Comment: Project Structure → Project Settings → Project добавила, а второй когда посмотрите вместо него - модератор не разрешает 2 добавлять(((

Comment: какой модератор? ну вот SDK тоже важно) и возможно он покажет что-то не то..

Comment: просто пишет, что я не могу добавить больше 1 картинки. Написала свой ответ и туда добавила скрин

Comment: добавила еще один скрин - может, оттуда что-то понятно будет....

Comment: сделайте инвалидацию кэшей и перезапуск idea

Comment: Я сделала инвалидацию кешей (п. 1 и п.2 в http://ru.androids.help/q2978). Но, все-равно, выдает ту же ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Помогла только переустановка винды