# Пустой код запускается только 1 раз

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdk11

Всё 1в1 как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611224/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-errorjava-c), но не хотелось бы переустанавливать винду. Может кто-то знает что нужно сделать спустя 5 лет? Делал инвалидацию кэшей и перезагружал ИДЕА. Переустанавливал jdk (скачивал и пробовал 18 версию - не помогло) переустанавливал ИДЕА тоже не помогло. Код билдится и ранится(да, не совсем пустой, автоматически сгенерированный ИДЕА), но только 1 раз. Если сделать перебилд, или написать что угодно, а затем стереть, то возникает ошибка.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Добавил в исключения WinDefender сам процесс ide, а так же папки из уведомления. Изменений нет. Так же попробовал отключить защитник винды - без изменений. Очень жду предложений, нужна помощь

Answer (score 1):

Пишет что нужно добавить в исключения защитника windows. Или антивируса. Попробуй отключить защитник и антивирус на время. И попробовать ещё раз запустить проект.

Comment: "Может попробовать "  - комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: Так пойдет? Не знал что есть разница.

Comment: Нет, я не о том. Смысл моего сообщения (это был комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений"). в том, что ответ должен представлять собой решение проблемы, а не догадку. Формулировка не так важна. Либо ответ может быть развернутым "исследованием" по теме, не влезающим в комментарий, что реже. Надо набрать 50 баллов репутации (например, два принятых ответа с плюсом или пять ответов с плюсом), и можно будет оставлять комментарии.

Comment: Тоесть помочь человеку догадкой я не могу? Пока не сделаю два стопроцентных ответа на другие вопросы? А сделать исследование я не могу потому что мне для этого нужна такая же проблема.

Comment: Кирилл, 1) я объяснил вам правила и практику сайта в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений" для действий на сайте в дальнейшем. 2) если бы вы вообще "не могли", то я бы запросил удаление вашего сообщения, я же об этом ничего не писал, так как мотивы ваши понятны и позитивны. 3) рекомендованные действия на будущее: набрать репутацию (это не сложно) и действовать согласно указанной практике. 4) Это мое последнее сообщение по данной теме, ничего нового я не смогу добавить: