# Смена версии java в intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как можно сменить версию Java в IDEA?

Comment: в смысле совсем версию или проверку синтаксиса и ошибок относительно выбранной версии?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если я правильно Вас понял, то второе. Я имею ввиду, импорт классов. Ибо даже при попытке создать 'JavaFX application' все импортированные классы подсвечены красным.

Comment: @Андрей правте ваш вопрос на основе комментариев.

Comment: Для каждого проекта надо менять версию jdk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то...

Попробуй в начале установить верную версию JDK в проект. Это описано в вопросе **[Не компилируется Java программа в IntelliJ Idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/607660/191482)**.

После установки (или если уже все и так было проделано), то зайди:

`Project Structure` → `Project Settings` → `Project` → `Project language level` и выбрать подходящий под проект уровень.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается, в project sdk стояла 1.7...